# Big Android Swap File

Tags: android, file, swap

I want to create a really big swap file on my Android phone or at least to try it.

System: Android 7.0
Phone: Samsung GALAXY S7 edge
Root: YES

I have already tried the ROEHSOFT RAM EXPANDER which works well but it allows me to create only max. 4 GB of swap file. I am talking about 20 GB or something like this. I know that it is crazy and may be unstable but I undergone every risk. I do not care about the speed. I would appreciate if you helped me and told me any guide how to do that. I undergone all the risks and the possibilites of crash of the phone. It is not my main phone so I do not care about it. I just need the RAM. Thanks everybody for help.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions, so this is off-topic here.

Comment: Okay, then I am sorry. I have seen some posts about swap here so I thought that this will be the right place for me.